# Web service that creates text file tries to create it on system making rest call, not locally as desired

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have a very simple C# web service written to handle offline domain joins for Windows builds.  Part of the offline domain join provision process is the creation of a .txt file that is then retrieved later in the process.  I have this web service dropping the .txt file in a folder that is locally on the web server which is a UNC share.  For some reason when I make a rest call to this service passing the parameter, the service tries to put the .txt file on my local machine in that directory, which doesn't exist so it errors out.  Why is it trying to put it on the machine of the box making the rest call, rather than locally?  Here is the pertinent code:

```
    public string ODJComputerName(string computername)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
        Process process;

        string path = Server.MapPath(".");
        string share = Server.MapPath("~");

        startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path + @"\djoin.exe");
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = share + @"\ODJ_files\";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        string outFile = startInfo.WorkingDirectory + computername + ".txt";

        startInfo.Arguments = "/provision /domain mydomain.com /machine " + computername + " /reuse /savefile " + outFile;

        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit(60000);
```

Comment: I'm sure you'll find that the service is doing exactly what you told it to do. The questions are: 1) What exactly did you tell it to do, \2) Why did you tell it to do that, and 3) How to tell it to do what you actually _wanted_ it to do?

Comment: The [Offline Domain Join (Djoin.exe)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/offline-domain-join-djoin-step-by-step(v=ws.10).aspx) documentation indicates nothing like the `/savefile` flag saving the file at the `/machine` machine (which is your claim, if I understand correctly). How did you observe this behavior? What is the exact error you receive?

Comment: When I make a the rest call from a remote server, I get:

`Invoke-RestMethod : Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EnterpriseAutomation\ODJ_files\HQSWL-C003072.txt' At C:\code\working\scripts\djoin_provision.ps1:10 char:1`


The share where I want the text to go is the first path.  But it's trying to save the .txt file locally on the remote box which doesn't have that path obviously.  I thought that since the web service was doing the work and running the code, it would copy the .txt file locally.